# How to remove the Name & Email popup in Captivate 9?

Tags: php, adobe, adobe-captivate

I am searching for the answer to this already for some days now, there are many posts but only few real answers so I hope you guys can help me.

I am coding (in PHP) an internal LMS using Adobe Captivate 9 where the results of the quiz are posted to "Internal Server". This works nice and I have changed the default InternalServerReporting script so it does push the results to our database so we can use them in our Admin console.
Every user who take a course needs to login first so we do already know the name and email address of this user, but still at the end of each quiz, Captivate gives the popup where it asks to enter the name and email address of the user:
[Post Results Name-Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XJcb.jpg)

Some months ago, when I was still using Captivate 8, I found a post somewhere (unfortunately I can't remember where) that pointed out to 1 setting that you can change (not in a menu, it was more in an ini file or regkey and as far as I remember even not in the project but more in the installed software) and that did the trick. Now I have upgraded to Captivate 9 and the same comes back but can't find that fix anymore.

Does anyone maybe know how to get rid of this popup in Captivate 9 or else know where to find that original answer that I found months ago?

Thanks
Micha

Answer (score 1):

For those that are trying to figure out the same, I found the answer by testing a lot myself.
When you call the Captivate Course, make sure to include the parameters:

- cpQuizInfoStudentID
- cpQuizInfoStudentName

So in stead of just calling https://someserver.com/course.htm you should call https://someserver.com/course.htm?cpQuizInfoStudentID=[ID]&cpQuizInfoStudentName=[Name]

This way it will parse both parameters inside the results XML without asking for them. You can even add more custom parameters in the same way and it will also be added to the XML.

Hope this helps you all.